# Oracle view sql comment error

Tags: sql, oracle, view

When I created a view, it had numerous carriage returns as well as some "--" comments documenting lines of the code.  Made-up example:

```
CREATE VIEW ... AS
SELECT
  P.ID AS PRODUCT_ID,
  P.PROD_DESC AS PRODUCT_DESC,
  P."COMMENT" AS PRODUCT_COMMENT,
  P.ACTIVE_IND AS PRODUCT_ACTIVE_IND,
  --
  SKU.SKU AS SKU,
  SKU.PRES_DESC AS SKU_PRESENTATION_DESC
FROM PRODUCTS P
  LEFT JOIN SKUS SKU ON P.PRODUCT_ID = SKU.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE P.DELETED = 0           -- Non-deleted products only
  AND SKU.DELETED = 0         -- Non-deleted SKUs only
  AND P.CAT_ID NOT IN (1, 3)  -- Exclude promo and sandbox items
ORDER BY P.ID
```

When initially instantiated, the view is fine, and when I export the DDL, it looks identical to the format as instantiated.  However, after some time, the view SQL gets reformatted, and mysteriously collapses a number of the lines into one, causing errors sometimes.  Example based on the above:

```
CREATE VIEW ... AS
SELECT
P.ID          AS PRODUCT_ID,
P.PROD_DESC   AS PRODUCT_DESC,
P."COMMENT"   AS PRODUCT_COMMENT,  P.ACTIVE_IND  AS PRODUCT_ACTIVE_IND,  SKU.SKU       AS SKU,  SKU.PRES_DESC AS SKU_PRESENTATION_DESCFROM PRODUCTS P  LEFT JOIN SKUS SKU ON P.PRODUCT_ID = SKU.PRODUCT_IDWHERE P.DELETED = 0 -- Non-deleted products only  AND SKU.DELETED = 0         -- Non-deleted SKUs only AND P.CAT_ID NOT IN (1, 3)  -- Exclude promo and sandbox itemsORDER BY P.ID
```

Couple notes on the result:

1. A padding gets added to the AS on the fields (previously was flush with the alias, e.g., "field AS alias" as opposed to suddenly all of the AS lining up, e.g., "field     AS alias".
2. At some point in the SQL (in this case, after the "COMMENT" field), all of the lines from then on lose their carriage returns.
3. Any of the comment lines with simply a double-dash (acting as a separator) disappear completely.

As mentioned, when the view is instantiated and I immediately get the DDL, it looks identical to how it was created.  However, at some point, the above happens.  Is there something on the Oracle side that goes through and attempts to reformat view SQL that would be causing this?  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: _"the view SQL gets reformatted, and mysteriously collapses a number of the lines into one, **causing errors sometimes**"_ What kind of errors could be caused by that "reformatting" ? AFAIK, removing comments, collapsing lines and adding some padding spaces _should_ not alter the SQL statement.

Comment: Nothing in Oracle itself is going to go through and reformat your view definition automatically.  If the DDL is changing, something in your environment is changing it-- either some process in your organization or some human in your organization.

Comment: You could try querying the data dictionary entry for the view (all_objects), and then checking the last_ddl_time value.  If the view really is mysteriously changing, the last_ddl_time value should reflect when the change occurred.  Maybe knowing **when** it changed can help you track down **what** made the change.

Comment: Which SQL client do you use to run those statements? Maybe you are affected by some of the strange limitations regarding comments in SQL*Plus? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1210782

Comment: Thank you for the responses.

1. If -- comments are interspersed between the lines of code and it's all placed into one line, everything after the first comment gets inadvertently commented out.

2. Confirmation that nobody has seen autoformatting or some such behavior is extremely useful to know.

3. I had looked at the last DDL time - it was more recent than it ought to have been.

4. Tool is SQL Developer.

Signs are kind of pointing to the work of an OCD DBA or someone using some kind of database cleanup type of tool.  Both seem horrifyingly unnecessary and risk-inducing.